# How to set the insertion point at the first line of textbox?

Tags: c#

How to set the insertion point at the first line of text box when I press enter if null value?

I used

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
{
    //some text
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Nothing happens though.

Comment: What do you mean with _"set the insertion point at the first line of text box "_? What is the insertion point, do you mean the caret? Do you have a multiline textbox? Where _does_ the caret appear after this code runs?

Comment: Set the SelectionStart property to 0.  I seriously doubt that's what the user will expect to happen.

Comment: What UI are you using? `winforms` or `wpf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "")
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty");
                textBox1.Focus();
                 }
           else 
           textBox2.Focus();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for failure:** you are assigning `Empty` `String` into `TextBox`  instead of Comparing

**Solution :** You need to check for `Empty String` using `if` Condition.

Try This:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
{    
    //some text
    if(textBox1.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))    
      textBox1.Focus();
   else
      textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple and useful

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
{

    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox1.SelectionStart = 1;

}
```